# Image of $|z|\leq R (R<1)$ under $w=1/(1-z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to find the image of $|z|\leq R$ where $R<1$ under the transformation $\frac{1}{1-z}.$ My attempt;
Let $w=\frac{1}{1-z}.$ Then $|w|\geq \frac{1}{1+|z|}\geq \frac{1}{1+R}.$ There fore image of $|z|\leq R$ lies in the region $|w|\geq \frac{1}{1+R}.$ How to extract the exact image of $|z|\leq R$ from this set? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Mobius images of circles are circles so this will be a disc though not necessary centered at the image of the origin; three points on the circle are the images of $\pm R$ and $iR$ say so find the circle passing through them etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Conrad;
Consider the points $(R,0), (-R, 0), (0, R)$ on the circle $|z|=R.$ Then the image points  under the Mobius transformation $1/(1-z)$ are $(1/(1-R), 0), 1/(1+R), 0), (1/(1+R^2), R/(1+R^2))$ Let the image circle $|z|=R$ under the mobius transformation $1/(1-z)$ be $C: (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2.$  Since the points $(1/(1-R), 0), 1/(1+R), 0), (1/(1+R^2), R/(1+R^2))$ are on $C,$ we have three equations;

$$(1/(1-R)-a)^2+b^2=r^2,$$$$ (1/(1+R)-a)^2+b^2=r^2,$$ $$ (1/(1+R^2)-a)^2+((R/(1+R^2)-b)^2)=r^2.$$
Solving we get  $a=1/(1-R^2), b=0, r=R/(1-R^2).$ Therefore the image of $|z|=R$ is a circle whose center is $1/(1-R^2)$ and radius is $R/(1-R^2).$ Hence the image of the disc $|z|\leq R$ is the disc with center $1/(1-R^2)$ and radius is $R/(1-R^2).$